# Change all accented letters to normal letters in C++

Tags: c++, c, string

### The question

How can you change all accented letters to normal letters in C++ (or in C)?

By that, I mean something like `eéèêaàäâçc` would become `eeeeaaaacc`.

### What I've already tried

I've tried just parsing the string manually and replacing each one of them one by one, but I was thinking there has to be a better/simpler way that I am not aware of (that would garantee I do not forget any accented letter).

I am wondering if there is already a map somewhere in the standard library or if all the accented characters can easily be mapped to the "normal" letter using some mathematic function (ex. `floor(charCode-131/5) + 61)`).

Comment: Where should the mapping be found?

Comment: That's what I am wondering.. Is there already such a map in the C library? Are all the char code easily mappable to the "normal" letter using some mathematic function (ex `floor(charCode-131/5) + 61)` or whatever..).. I'll add more details in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Doubtful. At best it'll be locale-dependent.

Comment: I think using `iconv` to convert to ASCII with the TRANSLIT option goes a long way towards what you want.

Comment: What's the encoding of the input? If it's latin1, you can just use a lookup table with replacement characters. If it's UTF-8, for example, you have the problem of normalization, which makes it hard.

Comment: How do you know it's ASCII? Some of us use EBCDIC (which is also locale dependent).

Comment: You may find a answer in: [Code to strip diacritical marks using ICU](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2992066/237483) or [Removing diacritic symbols from UTF8 string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4015879/237483)

Comment: Can someone tell me why is this conversion ever needed in anywhere?

Comment: What do you want this for?

Comment: @OneMore - Those accents do have meaning in certain languages. I guess you are not interested in losing that information

Comment: @Rookie Because many fonts don't have characters for accented letters. Think of OpenGL and other graphical interfaces for games, for instance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should first define what you mean by "accented letters" what has to be done is largely different if what you have is say some extended 8 bits ASCII with a national codepage for codes above 128, or say some utf8 encoded string.

However you should have a look at [libicu](http://site.icu-project.org/) which provide what is necessary for good unicode based accented letters manipulation.

But it won't solve all problems for you. For instance what should you do if you get some chinese or russian letter ? What should you do if you get the Turkish uppercase I with point ? Remove the point on this "I" ? Doing so it would change the meaning of the text... etc. This kind of problems are endless with unicode. Even conventional sorting order depends of the country...

Comment: Using ICU is the correct answer. It is already installed and available on every modern system, even devices like your iPhone and Android. You only need to link to it to use it. (How to do that depends on the system/OS, of course.)

Answer (score 13):

```
char* removeAccented( char* str ) {
    char *p = str;
    while ( (*p)!=0 ) {
        const char*
        //   "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ"
        tr = "AAAAAAECEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOx0UUUUYPsaaaaaaeceeeeiiiiOnooooo/0uuuuypy";
        unsigned char ch = (*p);
        if ( ch >=192 ) {
            (*p) = tr[ ch-192 ];
        }
        ++p; // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094621/
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This look as elegant solution but you should check the ch < 256 because on some platforms char > 255 and then the array will overflow for characters as Žž

Answer (score 7):

I know it only in theory. Basically, you perform Unicode normalization, then some decomposition, purge all diacritics, and recompose again.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values are just `char`s, I'd create an array with the desired target values and then just replace each character with the corresponding member in the array:

```
char replacement[256];
int n(0);
std::generate_n(replacement, 256, [=]() mutable -> unsigned char { return n++; });
replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('é')] = 'e';
// ...
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
               [&](unsigned char c){ return replacement[c]; });
```

Since the question is also tagged with C: when using C you'd need to create suitable loops to do the same operations but conceptually it would just same way. Similarily, if you can't use C++ 2011, you'd just use suitable function objects instead of the lambda functions.

Obviously, the `replacement` array can be set up just once and using a smarter approach than what is outlined above. However, the principle should work. If you need to replace Unicode characters thing become a bit more interesting, though: For one, the array would be fairly large and in addition the character may need multiple words to be changed.

Comment: "Assuming" --- that's one big assumption.

Comment: They aren't `char`s, at least if the input is UTF-8, which it should be.

Comment: @phihag: It seems the characters mentioned are covered by ISO/IEC 8859-1 (ISO Latin1). If this is sufficient why bother with UTF-8? Also, the statement about the formula seems to indicate a somewhat simplistic approach to represent these characters.

Comment: @DietmarKühl The characters may be *covered* by Latin-1, but are not necessarily *encoded* in Latin-1.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do using [ISO/IEC 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (ASCII-based standard character encoding):

- if code range is from `192 - 197` replace with `A`
- if code range is from `224 - 229` replace with `a`
- if code range is from `200 - 203` replace with `E`
- if code range is from `232 - 235` replace with `e`
- if code range is from `204 - 207` replace with `I`
- if code range is from `236 - 239` replace with `i`
- if code range is from `210 - 214` replace with `O`
- if code range is from `242 - 246` replace with `o`
- if code range is from `217 - 220` replace with `U`
- if code range is from `249 - 252` replace with `u`

Supposing x is the code of the number, perform the following for capital letters:

- `y = floor((x - 192) / 6)`
- if `y <= 2` then `z = ((y + 1) * 4) + 61` else `z = (y * 6) + 61`

Perform the following for small letters:

- `y = floor((x - 224) / 6)`
- if `y <= 2` then `z = ((y + 1) * 4) + 93` else `z = (y * 6) + 93`

The final answer `z` is the ASCII code of the required alphabet.
Note that this method works only if you are using [ISO/IEC 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: This worked form me in Java, I guess it should work in C++. Tell me if it doesn't.

Comment: It will certainly work with [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) in a trivial way, because there are no characters greater than 127 there. It may work with [something that is not ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), and it will probably not work with [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) [things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-3) [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-4) [are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-14) [not ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16).

Comment: If we are restricted to the 0-255 range I would probably use a lookup table instead of all those `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no easy way around here.

In application I work on this was solved by using internal codepage tables, each codepage table (like 1250, 1251, 1252, etc) contained actual codepage letter and non-diacritic equivalent. Tables were auto generated using c#, it contains some classes that really make that easy (with some heuristics actually), also java allows to implement it quicly.

This was actually for multibyte data with codepages, but it could be used for UNICODE strings (by just searching all tables for given unicode letter).

Comment: Im interested, why is this conversion ever needed?

Comment: ie. in searching, user will enter only ASCII characters but be allowed to search texts that contain characters with diacritics.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was needing to do a case-insensitive sort a long list of strings, where some of the strings might have diacriticals. So for instance I wanted "Añasco Municipio" to come right before "Anchorage Municipality", instead of coming right before "Abbeville County" as it was doing with a naive comparison.

My strings are encoded in UTF-8, but there's a chance that they might contain some extended ascii characters instead of proper UTF-8 Unicode. I could have promoted all strings to UTF-8, and then used a library that could do UTF-8 string comparison, but I wanted to have full control both for speed and for deciding exactly how diacritical characters are mapped to non-diacritical characters. (My choices include things like treating the masculine ordinal indicator as "o", and treating the copyright character as c.)

The "two-byte" codes below are UTF-8 sequences. The "one-byte" codes are extended ascii.

This is where I got the codes:

http://www.ascii-code.com/

http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php

```
void SimplifyStringForSorting( string *s, bool changeToLowerCase )
{
    // C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 AA // one-byte codes for "a"
    // C3 80 C3 81 C3 82 C3 83 C3 84 C3 85 C3 A0 C3 A1 C3 A2 C3 A3 C3 A4 C3 A5 C2 AA // two-byte codes for "a"
    
    // C8 C9 CA CB E8 E9 EA EB // one-byte codes for "e"
    // C3 88 C3 89 C3 8A C3 8B C3 A8 C3 A9 C3 AA C3 AB // two-byte codes for "e"
    
    // CC CD CE CF EC ED EE EF // one-byte codes for "i"
    // C3 8C C3 8D C3 8E C3 8F C3 AC C3 AD C3 AE C3 AF // two-byte codes for "i"
    
    // D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 BA // one-byte codes for "o"
    // C3 92 C3 93 C3 94 C3 95 C3 96 C3 B2 C3 B3 C3 B4 C3 B5 C3 B6 C2 BA // two-byte codes for "o"
    
    // D9 DA DB DC F9 FA FB FC // one-byte codes for "u"
    // C3 99 C3 9A C3 9B C3 9C C3 B9 C3 BA C3 BB C3 BC // two-byte codes for "u"
    
    // A9 C7 E7 // one-byte codes for "c"
    // C2 A9 C3 87 C3 A7 // two-byte codes for "c"
    
    // D1 F1 // one-byte codes for "n"
    // C3 91 C3 B1 // two-byte codes for "n"
    
    // AE // one-byte codes for "r"
    // C2 AE // two-byte codes for "r"
    
    // DF // one-byte codes for "s"
    // C3 9F // two-byte codes for "s"
    
    // 8E 9E // one-byte codes for "z"
    // C5 BD C5 BE // two-byte codes for "z"
    
    // 9F DD FD FF // one-byte codes for "y"
    // C5 B8 C3 9D C3 BD C3 BF // two-byte codes for "y"
    
    int n = s->size();
    int pos = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++, pos++ )
    {
        unsigned char c = (unsigned char)s->at( i );
        if ( c >= 0x80 )
        {
            if ( i < ( n - 1 ) && (unsigned char)s->at( i + 1 ) >= 0x80 )
            {
                unsigned char c2 = SimplifyDoubleCharForSorting( c, (unsigned char)s->at( i + 1 ), changeToLowerCase );
                if ( c2 < 0x80 )
                {
                    s->at( pos ) = c2;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // s->at( pos ) = SimplifySingleCharForSorting( c, changeToLowerCase );
                    // if it's a double code we don't recognize, skip both characters;
                    // this does mean that we lose the chance to handle back-to-back extended ascii characters
                    // but we'll assume that is less likely than a unicode "combining character" or other
                    // unrecognized unicode character for data
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                unsigned char c2 = SimplifySingleCharForSorting( c, changeToLowerCase );
                if ( c2 < 0x80 )
                {
                    s->at( pos ) = c2;
                }
                else
                {
                    // skip unrecognized single-byte codes
                    pos--;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( changeToLowerCase && c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )
            {
                s->at( pos ) = c + ( 'a' - 'A' );
            }
            else
            {
                s->at( pos ) = c;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( pos < n )
    {
        s->resize( pos );
    }
}

unsigned char SimplifyDoubleCharForSorting( unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2, bool changeToLowerCase )
{
    // C3 80 C3 81 C3 82 C3 83 C3 84 C3 85 C3 A0 C3 A1 C3 A2 C3 A3 C3 A4 C3 A5 C2 AA // two-byte codes for "a"
    // C3 88 C3 89 C3 8A C3 8B C3 A8 C3 A9 C3 AA C3 AB // two-byte codes for "e"
    // C3 8C C3 8D C3 8E C3 8F C3 AC C3 AD C3 AE C3 AF // two-byte codes for "i"
    // C3 92 C3 93 C3 94 C3 95 C3 96 C3 B2 C3 B3 C3 B4 C3 B5 C3 B6 C2 BA // two-byte codes for "o"
    // C3 99 C3 9A C3 9B C3 9C C3 B9 C3 BA C3 BB C3 BC // two-byte codes for "u"
    // C2 A9 C3 87 C3 A7 // two-byte codes for "c"
    // C3 91 C3 B1 // two-byte codes for "n"
    // C2 AE // two-byte codes for "r"
    // C3 9F // two-byte codes for "s"
    // C5 BD C5 BE // two-byte codes for "z"
    // C5 B8 C3 9D C3 BD C3 BF // two-byte codes for "y"
    
    if ( c1 == 0xC2 )
    {
        if ( c2 == 0xAA ) { return 'a'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xBA ) { return 'o'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xA9 ) { return 'c'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xAE ) { return 'r'; }
    }
    
    if ( c1 == 0xC3 )
    {
        if ( c2 >= 0x80 && c2 <= 0x85 ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'a' : 'A'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0xA0 && c2 <= 0xA5 ) { return 'a'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0x88 && c2 <= 0x8B ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'e' : 'E'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0xA8 && c2 <= 0xAB ) { return 'e'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0x8C && c2 <= 0x8F ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'i' : 'I'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0xAC && c2 <= 0xAF ) { return 'i'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0x92 && c2 <= 0x96 ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'o' : 'O'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0xB2 && c2 <= 0xB6 ) { return 'o'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0x99 && c2 <= 0x9C ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'u' : 'U'; }
        if ( c2 >= 0xB9 && c2 <= 0xBC ) { return 'u'; }
        if ( c2 == 0x87 ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'c' : 'C'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xA7 ) { return 'c'; }
        if ( c2 == 0x91 ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'n' : 'N'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xB1 ) { return 'n'; }
        if ( c2 == 0x9F ) { return 's'; }
        if ( c2 == 0x9D ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'y' : 'Y'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xBD || c2 == 0xBF ) { return 'y'; }
    }
    
    if ( c1 == 0xC5 )
    {
        if ( c2 == 0xBD ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'z' : 'Z'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xBE ) { return 'z'; }
        if ( c2 == 0xB8 ) { return changeToLowerCase ? 'y' : 'Y'; }
    }
    
    return c1;
}

unsigned char SimplifySingleCharForSorting( unsigned char c, bool changeToLowerCase )
{
    // C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 AA // one-byte codes for "a"
    // C8 C9 CA CB E8 E9 EA EB // one-byte codes for "e"
    // CC CD CE CF EC ED EE EF // one-byte codes for "i"
    // D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 BA // one-byte codes for "o"
    // D9 DA DB DC F9 FA FB FC // one-byte codes for "u"
    // A9 C7 E7 // one-byte codes for "c"
    // D1 F1 // one-byte codes for "n"
    // AE // one-byte codes for "r"
    // DF // one-byte codes for "s"
    // 8E 9E // one-byte codes for "z"
    // 9F DD FD FF // one-byte codes for "y"
    
    if ( ( c >= 0xC0 && c <= 0xC5 ) || ( c >= 0xE1 && c <= 0xE5 ) || c == 0xAA )
    {
        return ( ( c >= 0xC0 && c <= 0xC5 ) && !changeToLowerCase ) ? 'A' : 'a';
    }
    
    if ( ( c >= 0xC8 && c <= 0xCB ) || ( c >= 0xE8 && c <= 0xEB ) )
    {
        return ( c > 0xCB || changeToLowerCase ) ? 'e' : 'E';
    }
    
    if ( ( c >= 0xCC && c <= 0xCF ) || ( c >= 0xEC && c <= 0xEF ) )
    {
        return ( c > 0xCF || changeToLowerCase ) ? 'i' : 'I';
    }
    
    if ( ( c >= 0xD2 && c <= 0xD6 ) || ( c >= 0xF2 && c <= 0xF6 ) || c == 0xBA )
    {
        return ( ( c >= 0xD2 && c <= 0xD6 ) && !changeToLowerCase ) ? 'O' : 'o';
    }
    
    if ( ( c >= 0xD9 && c <= 0xDC ) || ( c >= 0xF9 && c <= 0xFC ) )
    {
        return ( c > 0xDC || changeToLowerCase ) ? 'u' : 'U';
    }
    
    if ( c == 0xA9 || c == 0xC7 || c == 0xE7 )
    {
        return ( c == 0xC7 && !changeToLowerCase ) ? 'C' : 'c';
    }
    
    if ( c == 0xD1 || c == 0xF1 )
    {
        return ( c == 0xD1 && !changeToLowerCase ) ? 'N' : 'n';
    }
    
    if ( c == 0xAE )
    {
        return 'r';
    }
    
    if ( c == 0xDF )
    {
        return 's';
    }
    
    if ( c == 0x8E || c == 0x9E )
    {
        return ( c == 0x8E && !changeToLowerCase ) ? 'Z' : 'z';
    }
    
    if ( c == 0x9F || c == 0xDD || c == 0xFD || c == 0xFF )
    {
        return ( ( c == 0x9F || c == 0xDD ) && !changeToLowerCase ) ? 'Y' : 'y';
    }
    
    return c;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it handles combining characters.

Comment: @melpomene: Then again, with UTF8 input, one can immediately remove all combining accents because there are no combining accents that map to an accent-less character in the lower ASCII range. (And thus you could argue that it should remove all Chinese characters, since *none* of these map to lower ASCII.)

Comment: melpomene and Rad Lexus: Thanks, yeah, I wasn't thinking about combining characters. I have modified the code to skip unrecognized two-character sequences (see comment in code), which will drop the combining codes, as well as other unrecognized two-byte sequences. I also now ignore unrecognized single-byte sequences, and hopefully this will handle Chinese, three-byte sequences, and so on, in a reasonable way. I realize all of this is strange trying to handle UTF-8 and extended ascii together, but hopefully it works well for English-centric sorting.

Comment: By the way, do you have a sense for how common combining characters are out there "in the wild" as compared to precomposed characters? My guess is that combining characters are relatively rare for the "normal" extended-ascii type characters like accents and graves on vowels, etc.?

Comment: Nice work; exactly what I was looking for!

question (for your long ago code): after the call to SimplifySingleChar, shouldn't `s->at( pos );` be `'s->at( pos ) = c2;`?

Comment: @mackworth, yes, sorry about that. I had actually fixed it long ago in my codebase but failed to fix it here.. It's fixed now.